# pyqt: how to remove elements from a QVBoxLayout?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I want a multi-color selection widget. The way I'm doing it is having a "+" button, and an initially empty vbox. When + is pressed, it adds a QHBoxLayout to the vbox containing a "-" button and 3 spinboxes. When the "-" button is pressed I want that row to disappear and everything to go back to looking like it did before that row was added.  The code I currently have is:

```
    vbox = self.ui.color_layout #from QtDesigner

    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    remove = QtGui.QPushButton("-", parent=self)

    remove.clicked.connect(lambda: vbox.removeItem(hbox))

    rspin = QtGui.QSpinBox(parent=self)
    gspin = QtGui.QSpinBox(parent=self)
    bspin = QtGui.QSpinBox(parent=self)

    hbox.addWidget(remove)
    hbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("R:", parent=self))
    hbox.addWidget(rspin)
    hbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("G:", parent=self))
    hbox.addWidget(gspin)
    hbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("B:", parent=self))
    hbox.addWidget(bspin)

    vbox.addLayout(hbox)
```

Adding widgets works fine. However, removing them results in a really messed-up looking thing where the row isn't actually removed, but the spacing is all messed up.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The docs say, for `removeWidget`:

> After this call, it is the caller's responsibility to give the widget a reasonable geometry or to put the widget back into a layout.

How do I do that? (I come from a GTK background...)

EDIT 2: I even kept track of the rows and called the `takeAt` function to remove it, but it still gets messed up. What gives? It looks like the layout is removed but none of the widgets are...

EDIT 3: this also doesn't work, just messes things up in a similar way:

```
    vbox = self.ui.color_layout

    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    row_widget = QtGui.QWidget(parent=self) #dummy widget to hold this stuff

    remove = QtGui.QPushButton("-", parent=self)

    def remove_func():
        vbox.removeWidget(row_widget)

    remove.clicked.connect(remove_func)

    rspin = QtGui.QSpinBox(parent=self)
    gspin = QtGui.QSpinBox(parent=self)
    bspin = QtGui.QSpinBox(parent=self)

    hbox.addWidget(remove)
    hbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("R:", parent=self))
    hbox.addWidget(rspin)
    hbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("G:", parent=self))
    hbox.addWidget(gspin)
    hbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("B:", parent=self))
    hbox.addWidget(bspin)

    row_widget.setLayout(hbox)

    vbox.addWidget(row_widget)
```

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try removing from parent widget, not the layout.

QLayout is not a parent, the parent for widgets being laid out is actually layout's parent. For more info and a clearer explanation see [documentation on Qt layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts).

To remove widget, set its parent to None like this:

```
widget = QWidget()    
layout = QVBoxLayout()

btn = QPushButton("To be removed")
layout.addWidget(btn)
widget.setLayout(layout)

# later
btn.setParent(None)
```

Comment: what's the parent widget? it's in a `QDialog` but it has [no remove function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog-members.html) of any kind. also weird.. i assume a qdialog was a container. i see a `children` function but apparently no way to put children in it..

Comment: i found the parent widget, but how do i remove it? there's no `removeChild` or anything..